# dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/bash

Tags: find, apt, package-management, dpkg, inode

What does it mean when package manager can not determine from which package the corresponding command was installed.
When I do -

```
$ sudo dpkg -S /usr/bin/passwd 
passwd: /usr/bin/passwd
```

from the output, I can infer that `passwd` was installed from `passwd` package

But for few command like - `ftp`, `bash`, `cat`, `ls` etc, the source info gives no lead about package. The below output is for `bash` but the output for other commands like `ftp`, `cat`, `ls` etc is exactly similar.

```
$ sudo dpkg -S /usr/bin/bash
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/bash
```

So, am puzzled what the above output means. Are these commands built in to shell or kernel (I don't think this is the case as commands/utils like `ls`, `cat` are part of coreutils package and man ls or cat confirms it.)

**So, what does it mean when package manager *can not determine from which package a command was installed.***

**Observation Notes:**

```
$ sudo apt list coreutils
Listing... Done
coreutils/focal,now 8.30-3ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

and

```
apt show coreutils | grep -Ew "ls|cat"
```

extract

> Specifically, this package includes:
> arch base64 basename **cat** chcon
> chgrp chmod chown chroot cksum comm cp  csplit cut date dd df dir
> dircolors dirname du echo env expand expr  factor false flock fmt fold
> groups head hostid id install join link ln  logname **ls** md5sum mkdir
> mkfifo mknod mktemp mv nice nl nohup nproc numfmt

**EDIT - Following Stephens response.**  (Posted as a separate Q too - [How to effectively trace hardlink in linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607524/how-to-effectively-trace-hardlink-in-linux)
Softlinks are easier to handle but Hardlinks are not easily traceable to orginal file -

```
$ ll -i /usr/bin/bash /bin/bash  
1310813 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1183448 Jun 18 21:14 /bin/bash*  
1310813 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1183448 Jun 18 21:14 /usr/bin/bash*
```

above is as expected - cool

```
$ find / -samefile /bin/bash 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/bash
```

again as expected - so no probs

```
find / -samefile /usr/bin/bash 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/bash
```

this is **NOT** cool. now how do i trace the org file now

Strange - below did not help either.

```
$ find / -inum 1310813 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/bash
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/bash`? Ubuntu  has bash at `/bin/bash`. Same for `/bin/cat` and `/bin/ls`.

Answer (score 3):

```
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/bash
```

means that no package ships `/usr/bin/bash` (directly). `dpkg -S` searches package contents, as shipped, ignoring alternatives, symbolic links etc.

```
dpkg -S /bin/bash
```

would find the package, because it ships `/bin/bash`.

See also:

```
$ dpkg -L bash|grep bin/bash
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bashbug
```

The same applies to `cat` and `ls` — they’re shipped in `/bin`. The best approach when looking for a command in this situation is to look for it prefixed with `bin/`:

```
$ dpkg -S bin/bash
bash: /usr/bin/bashbug
bash: /bin/bash
```

`ftp` *is* in `/usr/bin` but it’s an alternative; to find that, use `readlink`:

```
$ dpkg -S $(readlink -f /usr/bin/ftp)
ftp: /usr/bin/netkit-ftp
```

Comment: thanks, that helps greatly.  but still few concerns.. am posting them here

Comment: softlinks are ok to handle but hardlinks are not tracable to org file - `$ ll -i /usr/bin/bash /bin/bash
1310813 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1183448 Jun 18 21:14 /bin/bash*
1310813 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1183448 Jun 18 21:14 /usr/bin/bash*` - cool `$ find / -samefile /bin/bash 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/bash` - may be cool  ` find / -samefile /usr/bin/bash 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/bash` - this **NOT** cool. how do i trace the org file now

Comment: the outputs not cool here.. i will edit the Q

Comment: See my update to find the packages without having to care about links.