# What's the difference between two uname files

Tags: dpkg, which

I have to find the `uname` file on a Debian machine, check from which package it is and delete it. When I use `which` to find it, I get `/usr/bin/uname`. When I try to check it by `dpkg -S uname` there is no such file. There is a `/bin/uname` though. What is the difference between them?

Comment: Thank you for accepting an answer, but please accept Stephen's answer instead of mine. Mine is actually wrong: you _don't_ need the full path for `dpkg -S` as Stephen explained.

Comment: Oh, sorry i thought i could accept a couple of answears :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s no difference; in Ubuntu, [`bin` is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/Specs/Quantal/UsrMerge), some [Debian systems](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge), and various other distributions, so binaries appear in both locations.

Packages can ship files in either location; to find the package providing a given binary, look for `bin/` followed by the binary:

```
dpkg -S bin/uname
```

Comment: Wait, so `dpkg -S` does _not_ require a full path? Also, the OP is on Debian, not Ubuntu (in case that makes a difference). Also, I think part of the problem is that the OP used `which` which will just return the first hit in the PATH, so they only saw the one file, not two.

Comment: No, `dpkg -S` doesn’t require a full path ;-). I missed the part about Debian...

Comment: Of course you missed it: the OP had tagged with Debian, and I removed the tag (since this isn't a question about Debian per se) but like an idiot, forgot to add something to the question mentioning Debian. Sorry!

Comment: Ah, that explains it! I agree that using `which` is misleading, I didn’t think it worth re-explaining since you’d addressed that; I thought it worth explaining the `bin`/`usr/bin` merge since that is also confusing (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/607504/86440) for instance).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, use `type` or `type -a` to get all available `uname` files, not `which`. See [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/22222).

Next, when you want to see what package provides a given file, you can use the full path to the file (or just `bin/filename` if the file is a binary [as Stephen explains](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/618025/22222)) . For example, on an Ubuntu system, I get:

```
$ type -a uname
uname is /bin/uname
```

So this is what I need to pass to `dpkg -S`:

```
 $ dpkg -S /bin/uname
coreutils: /bin/uname
```

So, there you go. `/bin/uname` is provided by the `coreutils` package.

Comment: ... and deleting the `coreutils` package (which the OP mentioned that they might want to do) may result in a malfunctioning system.  Also, on some Linuxes, the `/usr/bin` and `/bin` executables will be the same.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, but since they say they "have to" I am assuming it's some sort of assignment. After all, if you choose to shoot yourself in the foot Mz Linux, just like Mr UNIX, will oblige...