# Debian everything-in-usr directory scheme (usrmerge) breaks dpkg -S. Work around?

Tags: debian, dpkg

I'm used to using `dpkg -S /path/to/file` to figure out where something came from on Debian. The ~new ["everything-in-usr"](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge) AKA usrmerge policy often breaks this. For just on example:

```
> dpkg -S /bin/systemd
systemd: /bin/systemd
> readlink -f /bin/systemd
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
> dpkg -S /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
```

This sucks because the actual executable running is /usr/lib/systemd/systemd so I'm much more likely to want to know what package that came from in any given usage of `dpkg -S`. Is there another usrmerge aware substitute for `dpkg -S` I could used to easily and reliably track an executable back to its package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’m not aware of any `/usr`-merge-aware equivalent to `dpkg -S`, but there is a way to avoid this problem: `dpkg -S` doesn’t need a full path, so

```
dpkg -S lib/systemd/systemd
```

and

```
dpkg -S bin/systemd
```

will give you the answer(s) you’re looking for. If you want to avoid listing all files matching the given patterns as substrings, add a `*`:

```
dpkg -S '*lib/systemd/systemd' '*bin/systemd'
```

See also [dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/607504/86440), and [this description of the `/usr` merge](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/MergedUsr) (written by the `dpkg` maintainer) which explains some of the constraints involved, and lists a number of `dpkg` features which are broken by the `usrmerge` package’s approach (including `dpkg -S`).